# NetBeans reading file from src, but writing to build folder

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans-8

NetBeans IDE 8.2 is reading a file from the src folder without problems. When I want the file to be written back to the same file, NetBeans is writing it to the build folder, and not back to the src folder.

File is located under

\ProjectName\src\main\resources\player.csv

and is fired from the file PresentationModel.java which is located in

\ProjectName\src\main\presentationmodel\PresentationModel.java

```
private final String fileName = "../resources/player.csv";

    private Path getPath(String fileName, boolean locatedInSameFolder) {
    try {
        if (!locatedInSameFolder) {
            fileName = "/" + fileName;
        }
        return Paths.get(getClass().getResource(fileName).toURI());
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
    }
}

private Stream<String> getStreamOfLines(String fileName, boolean locatedInSameFolder) {
    try {
        return Files.lines(getPath(fileName, locatedInSameFolder), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
}

private List<Player> readFromFile() {
    try (Stream<String> stream = getStreamOfLines(fileName, true)) {
        return stream.skip(1)
                .map(s -> new Player(s.split(";")))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Save function is:

```
public void save() {
    try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(getPath(fileName, true))) {
        writer.newLine();
        data.stream()
                .map(player -> player.infoAsLine())
                .forEach(line -> {
                    try {
                        writer.write(line);
                        writer.newLine();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
                    }
                });

    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("save failed");
  Logger.getLogger(PresentationModel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

When I fire the save function I get the following folder structure:

> ProjectName\build\resources\main\resources\player.csv

When I re-run the program, the file is not modified because it's re-taken from the src folder.

Has anyone an idea how to fix this?

Best Regards.

Comment: I don't really believe it can be reading from the `src` folder structure. Can you actually log the values you get from `getPath(...)` in each case? I suspect that what is happening is that you rebuild the project each time, and you are overwriting the `player.csv` file in the `build` folder with the one in the `src` folder, which is unchanged. You probably want to rethink this strategy anyway: when you bundle your application as a jar file, the resource you get will not be writable. Usually you would use a subdirectory of the user's home directory for this kind of functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I don't understand why the files are copied every time to the build folder from scratch when I run the program (shift+F6 or right click in AppStarter -> Run File). So you're right, the unchanged file is copied each time to the build folder. So my question would be, how can I leave the files in the build folder unchanged until I explicitly press "build" or "clean"?

Comment: Like I said, just don't do it that way. In general you cannot assume that the build folder is going to be writable at runtime anyway (most of the time, after deployment, `getPath()` in your code is not even going to give a file URL, it will give a jar URL). The classpath is simply not the correct location for a file that has this kind of functionality.